# JSPlumb v1.4.1 draggable/resizable example not working anymore with v2.0.7

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jsplumb

I need to connect draggable and resizable `<div>` elements with JSPlumb.
I was looking at this [tutorial](http://www.freedevelopertutorials.com/jsplumb-tutorial/drag-resize/) it uses v1.4.1 of JSPlumb. I have a very simmilar code as the example in the [tutorial](http://www.freedevelopertutorials.com/jsplumb-tutorial/drag-resize/):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <style>
        #diagramContainer {
            padding: 20px;
            width:80%; height: 400px;
            border: 1px solid gray;
        }

        .item {
            position: absolute;
            height:80px; width: 80px;
            border: 1px solid blue;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="diagramContainer">
        <div id="item_left" class="item"></div>
        <div id="item_right" class="item" style="left:150px;"></div>
    </div>

    <p><a href="http://www.freedevelopertutorials.com/jsplumb-tutorial/introduction/">Visit the full jsPlumb-Tutorial</a> to learn it and see many more interesting examples.</p>

    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jsPlumb/1.4.1/jquery.jsPlumb-1.4.1-all-min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(".item").resizable({
        resize : function(event, ui) {            
                jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper);
            }
        });

        jsPlumb.ready(function() {           

            jsPlumb.connect({
                source:"item_left",
                target:"item_right",
                endpoint:"Rectangle"
            });

            jsPlumb.draggable("item_left");
            jsPlumb.draggable("item_right");
        });
    </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

( Here is a jsFiddle like demonstration: http://www.freedevelopertutorials.com/jsplumb-tutorial/examples/jsplumb-resizable-divs-example/ of the code)

If I switch the JSPlumb version in the sample code above from v1.4.1 to v2.0.7 `resizing`an element also starts `dragging`it.

I found the following stackoverflow question [jsPlumb issue using drag and resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31755552/jsplumb-issue-using-drag-and-resize) but I could not understand the answer.

**I tried the following:**

1. not using `jsPlumb.draggable("item_left");` and instead just

   ```
           $(".item").draggable({
           drag: function (event, ui) {
               jsPlumb.repaint(ui.helper);
           }
       });
   ```

Then the line gets drawn but does not follow the resize/drag
movement of the items.

**Can anybody tell me how to get the example to work with the new version?**
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

For the newer versions of JsPlumb the bug persists. In this case, just use the filter option in the drag options.

```
jsPlumb.draggable((element), {
   filter: ".ui-resizable-handle"
});
```

https://github.com/jsplumb/katavorio/wiki#filtering